# Svg image change color problem below ios13

Tags: ios, svg, uistoryboard, xib

I used most of assets as svg with universal and rendering mode template image. I colored images with tint color in xib or storyboard. It runs correctly on ios 13 but, below ios 13 it doesnt render image colors. It show always black until showing an alert controller. When I show alert controller svg image colors setting then.

Whats is wrong? Is there any way rendering colors when viewdidload?

SOLVED EDIT:

1. set imageview bg transparent(clearColor)
2. set tint color programmatically

Thats worked

Comment: https://cloudconvert.com/svg-to-pdf

Comment: I forgot to write, I add svg files as pdf

Comment: still does not work for me? changed svg into pdf, cleare bg and tint color.